# Create HLS video stream from PyAV av.VideoFrame

Tags: python, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, pyav, aiortc

I hope you are loud and proud.

I'm a newbie to `PyAV` and I'm using `aiortc` for WebRTC MediaServer, in an `aiortc` live session I have `av.VideoFrame` objects available for each video frame and I want to create HLS video segments from the frames in real-time.

As you can see in [this project](https://gist.github.com/hiorws/92b65b55aae588a078a0e101aba266fe):
They have used `OpenCV` video frame bytes piped to `FFmpeg` CLI for HLS streaming

My question is, how can I use `PyAV`/`python` for consuming `av.VideoFrame` objects and extract 2-second video segments consisting of 60 frames for HLS streaming?

Or any python package appropriate for assembling VideoFrames to HLS stream

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's been a year, my friendly advice is not to use `aiortc` at all and just use `MediaSoup` instead

Comment: Did you solve your problem with `MediaSoup`? Did you use [PyMediasoup](https://pypi.org/project/pymediasoup/)? Have you tried to write your video frames to `io.BytesIO` and pass it to `MediaPlayer`, see https://aiortc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#media-sources

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing some terms. I assume that HLS refers to HTTP-Streaming. WebRTC is a different way (protocol) to send video (P2P). `aiortc` is not a MediaServer, even though you can do something similar. You can use `aiortc` as WebRTC client that sends a video track to a browser (another WebRTC client). The connection can be established using a HTTP server as signaling server.

I assume in the following that you like to stream your video using `aiortc` (WebRTC).

### How to transform frames of a track (e.g. from webcam)?

If I understand you correctly, your actuall question is "How to transform frames of a track (e.g. from webcam)?". [Here](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/c29eb4aa2a3ea0fae08d0467c2c342c497f23125/examples/server/server.py#L23-L90) is a runnable example that uses `MediaStreamTrack` to implement `VideoTransformTrack`. However, this example receives the webcam image from the browser (other client). Have a look at [this](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/tree/ffe2a566da74e000fc5bef354ae3f0a9a90c40e2/examples/webcam) example, which uses the webcam of your server (Python application). Just add

```py
pc.addTrack(VideoTransformTrack(video, transform="rotate"))
```

to the `RTCPeerConnection` (`pc` in the snippet above) with `video` returned from `create_local_tracks`.

### How to create track from frames?

```py
class MyMediaStreamTrack(MediaStreamTrack):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        # use webcam as source of frames in this example
        self.frames = av.open(file="/dev/video0").decode()
        self.kind = 'video'

    async def recv(self):
        # read next av.VideoFrame
        frame = next(self.frames)
        # optional: transform/consume frame
        frame = self._transform(frame)
        return frame
    
    def _transform(self, frame):
        img = frame.to_ndarray(format="bgr24")
        rows, cols, _ = img.shape
        M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols / 2, rows / 2), frame.time * 45, 1)
        img = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (cols, rows))

        # rebuild a VideoFrame, preserving timing information
        new_frame = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(img, format="bgr24")
        new_frame.pts = frame.pts
        new_frame.time_base = frame.time_base
        return new_frame


pc = RTCPeerConnection()
pc.addTrack(MyMediaStreamTrack())
```